# 2 step authentication C# Access JSON API via SSIS 2010

Tags: ssis

I have managed in SSIS 2010 to access a JSON API with basic authentication ... Username and password, using the script below

I need to amend the script below to also include passing credentials of a Client Secret and Client ID

anyone know how to amend this for SSIS 2010. I have tried with no joy, so I have pasted the working code so far

Please help

```
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"https://sub.domain.com/api/operations?  param=value&param2=value");
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String  (Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username:password"));
    //req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Comment: I speculate that this is some sort of oauth or oauth2 authorization maybe since you're talking about client secret and Id.  If that's the case it's not as simple as just modifying what you have with a few lines.  You'd be looking at adding an additional class that handles constructing the authorization header.   All dependent on the specific API you are interacting with, which I hope has documentation.

Comment: Hi ..I did try using Zappysys that works well. this uses OAUTH. I need to code this please. Trying to do this without no 3rd party, also it is only a 30 Day trail

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on how the API is set up and what it's expecting, but in my case, I did this in the creation of an [HttpClientHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=netframework-4.8):

```
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Configuration;
    ...
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API.UserName"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API.Password"].ToString()) };
    HttpClient apiClient = new HttpClient(handler);
```

OR, without using Configurations:

```
    using System.Net.Http;
    ...
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MyUserName", "MyPassword") };
    HttpClient apiClient = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Then use the Client to make calls.   Here's how I do it:

```
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = apiClient.GetAsync(curl).Result;
```

Comment: Hi, I have added the assembly reference for the http. the code seems to have issues with the words 'Static' and 'ConfigurationManager'. I am not fay sorry with coding in C#

Comment: You don't have to use the configuration manager, and it sounds like you should just hard-code the credentials in your string.   But if you do use configurations, you need to also add `using System.Configuration;`.  Also you don't need to use `static` at all, though I have no idea why your code would have a problem with it.   I have adjusted my answer.